# Oracle Delete and Insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update the categories linked to a row. A row can be linked to multiple categories. To visually represent this, please take a look at the following simplified scenarios:

#### Object Table

```
id    name
----------
1     Chair
2     Computer
```

#### Category Table

```
id    category
--------------
90    Asset
100   Furniture
200   Electronics
300   Garbage
```

#### Linking Table

```
obj   cat
---------
1     90
1     100
2     90
2     200
```

So I have those values in the database right now. But now I decided to update the `Chair` record to be both `100 | Furniture` and `300 | Garbage`.

How do I go about doing this efficiently? I know I can delete all of the associated links, then add the new links but there must be a more efficient way for me to do this.

Comment: Your statement is correct: You have to delete the old information and  add the new one. Even if you could do that in a single sweep ( which is only possible in a straightforward way, if no link replacement ever changes the the number of links for a given object ), the db would still have to visit every single record and change it. Expect a bulk delete followed by a bulk insert to be more efficient, especially if the sets of linking records to be deleted and inserted, resp., can be formulated as a db query.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. But I think it's highly inefficient. I don't know, I'm not really well-versed into database management. I was reading on MERGE but I don't know if that could help me or not.

Comment: It appears that the `id` columns are the primary key on the Object and Category tables. There are three things that a primary key must always be: 1) NOT NULL, 2) unique, and 3) **UNCHANGING**. What you're suggesting violates rule #3. Primary key values should ***NEVER*** be changed - otherwise you encounter exactly this situation.

Comment: @BobJarvis Sorry I don't get what your point is. I wasn't going to change anything on both the `Object` and the `Category` tables. I was just going to change the foreign keys on the `Linking` table.

Comment: My mistake - I thought you were updating the Object and Category tables - but oddly enough, my point still holds. In the Linking table the primary key is (or should be) [obj, cat] - and since these are elements of the primary key they should never be changed. Thus, you should delete the existing rows in Linking, insert the new Linking rows, and then commit the transaction. Also note that if you have foreign key constraints from e.g. Linking.obj to Object.id, and Linking.cat to Category.id, you should have indexes on Linking on (obj, cat) and (cat, obj). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different options you could take:

1. Update the existing rows if the number of rows in the `Linking Table` isn't changing. In this case, you could update the row with `1 90` to be `1 300`. The challenge here is ensuring the number of rows to remove is equal to the number you plan on inserting.
2. Delete the ones no longer valid and insert new ones for the rows missing. Note that in this case, the `1 100` row would still stay intact just like the first case though this doesn't have the requirement of the # of rows to delete = # of rows to insert.

[Nuke n Pave](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nuke%20n%20pave) would be what you initially suggest of deleting all the data and starting over again that could be overkill.